# Could Zuul-Server SNAPSHOT be broken?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am build a project that was working before using Spring Cloud snapshot build. Everything seems to work except Zuul Server. I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to load 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
```

This brought be to add the following dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

This leads to another exception:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate
```

At which point I gave up patching my POM. I then went to clone the Zuul project on GIT. Unfortunately I am getting the same problems.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with the spring cloud samples version of zuul server.  After I added the spring boot starter web and actuator it went away.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a change in the dependency structure. I don't even know why you need an EL implementation, but tomcat-embed-el is probably the best one to include. And the other class is from spring-web.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Adding tomcat-embed-el still results into java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.

Comment: That's why I said you need spring-web.

Comment: Most apps in this class would already be using spring-boot-starter-web which has everything in it (that's why none of the samples raised this issue yet).

Comment: I tried combinations of adding spring-web, spring-boot-starter-web, and tomcat-embed-el. I consistently get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/MvcEndpoint. I am using the Github Zuul-Server project for this test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The two following dependencies fix the problem: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-actuator. Please consider adding them to the spring cloud examples in github.

Comment: All the examples work as far as I know. Those two dependencies would be included transitively from something else probably.